# Extending $\Bbb N$ to a semiring with isomorphic additive and multiplicative structure

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, extension, semirings

Seen $(\Bbb N,+,\cdot)$ as a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), is it possible to extend it to a semiring $(R,+,\cdot)$ so that the additive and multiplicative monoids become isomorphic? This means there is some monoid-isomorphism

$$\varphi:(R,\cdot)\cong(R,+)$$

and $\Bbb N$ is a sub-semiring of $R$. Here, $\Bbb N$ is meant to include $0$. I do not think that there is such an extension, but I cannot find a contradiction. I also wonder if the problem becomes easiert when asking for an isomorphism

$$\varphi:(R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)\cong(R,+)$$

instead?

---

**Observations**

The multiplication will be commutative. Also, there will be *many* new "numbers", e.g. a unique additively absorbing element $\eta:=\varphi(0)$, i.e. $\eta+x=\eta$ for all $x\in R$. For $n\in\Bbb N^+$ we have

$$n\cdot \eta=\underbrace{\eta+\cdots+\eta}_n=\eta.$$

Therefore we have further elements $\tilde\eta=\varphi(\eta)$ that absorbe *some* numbers when added to them, e.g. $\varphi(n),n\in\Bbb N^+$, but not all (there can be only one universally absorbing element).

Comment: How do you prove that $\varphi(0)$ additively absorbs all elements of $R$ and not just those of $\varphi(\mathbb N)$? Ahh, I got it: I stumbled again on the definition of semiring and the assumption that $R$ is a semiring.

Comment: The monoids are almost isomorphic already under logarithm. So add countable many zeros to each monoid, and extend freely to a semiring.  Gerhard "Equations Allow Building Your Own" Paseman, 2017.07.16.

Comment: It seems to me that we are trying to formally close $\mathbb N$ by both $\log$ and $\exp$, besides $+$ and $\cdot$, but thought of in terms of a generic base (rather than $e$) and only the expressions that simplify because of general properties of $\log$ and $\exp$, regardless of base, do so. The question then would be whether we can run into a contradiction, like 0=1, presumably by enforcing distributivity?

Comment: Nice question. Why would the operations be commutative?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you. The addition is commutative my the definition of semiring and the commutativity of the multiplication follows from the existence of the isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, ok, commutativity of $+$ is part of the definition. Thanks.

Comment: Can you suggest a nontrivial semiring whose additive and multiplicative monoids are isomorphic? I'm not sure if this would be easier, but is there an extension of, say, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ to a semiring like this?

Comment: @ZachTeitler For example $[0,1]$ with $a+b=\max(a,b)$ and $a\cdot b=\min(a,b)$. Unfortunatly this example is idempotent and the only one I know of.

Comment: @M.Winter: Do you assume semirings have an additive unit, additive zero, or multiplicative unit?

Comment: @KeithKearnes I added a link to the definition I use. It has an additive unit $0$, multiplicative unit $1$ and the $0$ is multiplicatively absorbing.

Comment: @M.Winter: Do you assume that substructures share the same 0 and 1 as the whole structure? (So, here, must the 0 and 1 of $\mathbb N$ be the same as the 0 and 1 of $R$?)

Comment: @KeithKearnes I assumed it, but I also assumed that this can be deduced anyway. Am I wrong? As far as I can see $R$ can contain only one unit for addition/multiplication and one absorbing element anyway, and so they have to be the same as for $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @M.Winter: No, that argument is not correct. Your example of a semiring [0,1] has unit element 1 and zero element 0, but it contains a subsemiring [.1,.9] whose unit is .9 and whose zero is .1.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Ah, embarassing! Thank you for pointing this out. Then I would say it that way: I was hoping to have the same unities and absorbing elements in $R$ and $\Bbb N$ but I will not require it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an extension $R$: take the closure of $\mathbb N$ by the operations $\text{L}$ (or $\varphi$ in the OP) and its inverse $\text{E}$, which are the logarithm and exponential in base $1.2$. Notice that the choice of base (see below) implies that all ***new*** numbers generated by repeated applications of the 4 operations ($+$, $\cdot$, $\text{L}$ and $\text{E}$) are $\gt 1$, except for infinities, so that there is never a need to apply $\text{L}$ to negative numbers.

For infinities impose the following rules:

$0\cdot x=0$

$\text{L}(0)+x=\text{L}(0)$

$\text{L}(0)\cdot x=\text{L}(0)$ if $x\ne0$

$\text{L}(\text{L}(0))+x=\text{L}(\text{L}(0))$ if $x\ne \text{L}(0)$

$\text{L}(\text{L}(0))\cdot x=\text{L}(\text{L}(0))$ if $x\ne \text{L}(0),0$

$\text{L}(\text{L}(\text{L}(0)))+x=\text{L}(\text{L}(\text{L}(0)))$ if $x\ne \text{L}(\text{L}(0)),\text{L}(0)$

...

These rules obey the semiring axioms and cover all possibilities for mixing reals and infinities. Notice also that $\text{L}(0)$, $\text{L}(\text{L}(0))$, $\text{L}(\text{L}(\text{L}(0)))$ etc. are then the only non-reals in $R$.

As for the choice of a base $\lt\sqrt{2}$, notice that if $a=1.2577...$ is the solution to $1.2^a=a$, then both $\text{L}(x)>a$ and $\text{E}(x)>a$ if $x>a$ and therefore the only finite elements in this model $R$ that can be $<a$ are $0$, $1$, $\text{E}(1)$, $\text{E}(\text{E}(1))$, $\text{E}(\text{E}(\text{E}(1)))$ etc.

**Update**. A much simpler model is the *completion* of the one above, but with $\sqrt{2}$ as the base:

$ \text{L(x)}=\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)$, $\text{E}(x)=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{x}$ its inverse, and

$R= \{\dots\ \text{L}^3(0), \text{L}^2(0), \text{L}(0), 0, 1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}\dots\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb R| x\ge 2\}$

with the same rules for infinities as already explained.

Comment: I think this model is what Gerhard meant in one of his comments, with details filled in.

Comment: Notice that this same model, *if we strip the infinities*, also answer the second question in the OP, since $\text{L}$ is then an isomorphism $(R\backslash\{0\},\cdot) \rightarrow (R,+)$.

Comment: Chosing $\sqrt{2}$ itself as the base also still works.

Comment: For the record, I have implemented these rules (for the completed version with base $\sqrt{2}$) in Maple and thereby checked that there are not any hidden problems with the semiring axioms. A very interesting example!

Comment: In fact, if we write $b \uparrow \uparrow n$ for the tower of powers of $b$ of height $n$, and $b_k$ for the (unique) solution to $b_k \uparrow \uparrow k = 2$, then $b_k > \sqrt{2}$ should also be a suitable base so long as the sequence of values $b_k \uparrow \uparrow n$ is bounded (which it is when $b_k < e^{1/e}$, true for $k \ge 5$).

Comment: But surely then $\text{L}^4(2) < b$? A base larger than $\sqrt{2}$ requires $b \uparrow \uparrow k = 2$ for some $k$, does it not?

Comment: @RobinSaunders: sorry for the crossing - I was still editing my comments... Here is my reason why it won't work: if $b=e^{1/e}$ then $\text{L}^5(2)<1$. What you meant in your last comment is that there may be a smart choice of a $b>\sqrt{2}$ that avoids negatives by the $\text{L}$ tower from $2$ hitting $1$ exactly?

Comment: I see now that that is what you said all along in your first comment. Good point!

Comment: It's now occurred to me that with $b > \sqrt{2}$, we need to worry about iterated logarithms not only of $2$ but also of other sums of elements falling below $\sup_n b \uparrow \uparrow n$...

Comment: However, for $k \ge 5$, $1 + b_k > \sup_n b_k \uparrow \uparrow n$, so I *think* this shouldn't be a problem.